# Disable Code Assist in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: aptana, code-assist

Is there any way to disable code assist in Aptana Studio 3? It is driving me absolutely insane! It changes things I don't want changed, it just overall gets in the way of my workflow. It was never a problem until the most recent update and ever since that update it's been much more aggressive in it's "assisting." I just want to be able to write the code myself without it messing me up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue you are referring to is most likely resolved in the beta of 3.0.4, but if you need to turn code assist off, I would suggest:

a) Preferences > Aptana > Editors (main node)

b) Preferences > Aptana > Editors > JavaScript (for example) and check the activation triggers. You may wish to remove "(" and "." for example.

Answer (score 14):

To Caldwell,

The thing that you have mention is called **Content Asisst**. It will show a code-assist when you typing a code related to HTML/CSS.

To disable Content Assist in Aptana Studio 3 is :
Choose **Window** in the main menu ( menu avaiable on top) → **Preferences** → Choose **Aptana Studio** → **Content Assist** → Look at the **Auto-display content asisst** then you will see the **drop down menu** at besides, then click drop-down menu choose **Off** instead of **Default delay**.

That's all. Thank you

Comment: -1 because pretty much the exact same answer was given and accepted almost a year ago.

Comment: This also solved my issue with the unwanted folder drop downs and code insertions I was talking about in my comment on the main question. Thank you!

Comment: I needed the information in both answers.  They are complementary.

Comment: Agreed, this is what I wanted, not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Found this article trying to turn off the auto-complete of quotes and html tags. This feature is called **auto-close**. It can be turned off in Windows by going to **Window -> Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Editors**. Here there is a "**Typing**" section of options. Unchecking "**Auto-close matching character pairs**" and "**Wrap selected text with matching characters**" did the trick for me.