# Disable code assist for Ruby code

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, aptana

I see a number of solutions for disabling code assist for languages other than Ruby (an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988785/disable-code-assist-in-aptana-studio-3), which doesn't work), but I can't find any means of disabling it when working in Ruby. This is with Aptana Studio 3.2.0.

Is there a way, even under the hood, to turn it off that I'm missing?